# Number of ways to place k 2x2 squares in a nxn grid

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider an **n by n** grid. How many ways can I place **k** 2x2 squares in the grid? The squares don't have to be aligned with each other, as long as they are aligned with the grid. Squares can't overlap and can't be split.

For example: For **n=4, k=3**, the configuration below is valid! (Letters represent squares, I can't post pictures yet, sorry)

> A A - -
>
> A A B B
>
> C C B B
>
> C C - -

A simpler version of this problem would be the number of ways to place **k** 1x2 rectangles on a **1 by n** grid

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You may want to take a look at the [editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) that will both help you to edit your post to make it look better.

Comment: This is an interesting (and maybe hard) question. Have you calculated the exact answer for small $n$ (say $n\le7$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. I followed the suggestion of Greg Martin and wrote a tiny program to get the first values of the sequence. Then plugging this sequence in the OEIS you get

T(n,k) = number of ways to place k nonattacking kings on an n X n board 
(https://oeis.org/A193580)

This is, I think, an equivalent way to describe your problem (you have to consider the "dual" grid and place the kings at intersections to obtain yours).

Bottom line is that this is a known problem but there doesn't seem to be a closed formula answer.

Comment: I think you can solve my n X n problem by considering the n-1 X n-1 non attacking kings problem, and placing the top left cell of the square on the king

Comment: I don't really wanna draw the picture but if you consider the king's moves you see that it covers 9 squares on a chessboard (assuming you are not on some special position on the side). Now if you look to your problem, if you put dots on the intersections of the grid then each 2x2 square covers exactly 9 dots, so you get the correspondence. And indeed you have to consider n-1xn-1 because of the king could be on  a side (and a square cannot)

Comment: This is true, but we can still place kings with a 1 tile gap between them, just like the top left corners of 2x2 squares